# recently i build discord bot, the main problem is, i dont know how to set the permission, so every member of my server can kick and ban others

Tags: javascript, discord.js

module.exports = {
name: 'ban',
description: "This command bans a member!",
execute(message, args){

```
    const member = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(member){
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
        memberTarget.ban();
        message.channel.send("User has been banned");
    }else{
        message.channel.send('you couldnt ban that member');
    }
}
```

}

module.exports = {
name: 'kick',
description: "This command kicks a member!",
execute(message, args){

```
    const member = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(member){
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
        memberTarget.kick();
        message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
    }else{
        message.channel.send('you couldnt kick that member');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

We could simply check for a user's permission using the `.hasPermission()` function of the `GuildMember` object. We could simply integrate it with a simple if statement, that would include the permissions you want to check for:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS') return; // Would return if the message author does not have permission to Ban Members
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS') return; // Same thing for the Kick Members permission.
```